# Struggling with regex in javascript to take a matched part of a string and use that to replace another part

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an expression in the middle of a bunch of html (actually an rss feed) of the form

```
<a href="javascript://">by unknownstring</a>
```

where **unknownstring** can be any string containing alphanumerics, including dashes, but it won't contain spaces nor slashes. Effectively, it's a directory name.
I need to be able to change it to:

```
<a href="http://zazzle.com/unknownstring*">by unknownstring</a>
```

I've been reading up about regex but most of it's going over my head. Unfortunately I don't understand enough to make sense of most of what I've read here and in other places.

Help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
str = '<a href="javascript://">by unknownstring</a>'
regex = /\<a href="javascript:\/\/"\>by (\w+)\<\/a\>/
replacement = '<a href="http://zazzle.com/$1*">by $1</a>'

console.log(str.replace(regex, replacement));
// <a href="http://zazzle.com/unknownstring*">by unknownstring</a>
```

Here's [some material](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=hea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript%20regex%20replace&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=e38c2442c5020f97&ix=hea&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1340&bih=739) that I used. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using different match pieces where you substitute one match piece for another, you can do it like this:

```
var html = '<a href="javascript://">by unknownstring</a>';
html = html.replace(/(<a\s+.*?href=['"])(javascript:\/\/)(.*?>by\s+)(.*?)(<\/a>)/g, "$1$4$3$4$5");
alert(html);
```

You can see this one work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KgN7t/.  Conceptually, we write a regex to match all the different pieces of the match string and then we replace the whole thing while substituting one piece for another.  Each piece in the regex is delineated with parens.

Or you can use a similar concept, but with a custom replace function like this:

```
var html = '<a href="javascript://">by unknownstring</a>';
html = html.replace(/<a\s+.*?href=['"](javascript:\/\/).*?>by\s+(.*?)<\/a>/g, function(str, p1, p2) {
    return(str.replace(p1, p2));
});
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ewnqj/

Comment: Thank you everyone - that's helped me tremendously and answered my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Regex it like this:

```
var str = '<a href="javascript://">by unknownstring</a>';
var regx = '<a href="javascript://">by (.*)</a>';
var output = '<a href="http://zazzle.com/$1">by $1</a>';
str.replace(RegExp(regx),output);
```

Enjoy!